# Dropping multiple ranges of rows in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

If we have a Pandas DataFrame of, for example, size (100, 5) and want to drop *multiple ranges of rows* (not multiple rows or a range of rows, but *multiple ranges of rows*) by indices, is there a way to do it without having to loop over the indices?

As an example, if I want to drop the rows of a Pandas DataFrame `df` between the indices (3, 10), (24, 29), and (31, 64), a naive approach would be

```
for pair in [(3, 10), (24, 29), (31, 64)]:
    a, b = pair
    df.drop(df.iloc[a:b].index, inplace=True)
```

But I was hoping there's a way to drop the ranges of rows all at once.

Thank you.

Comment: ```df.drop(np.r_[3:10,24:29,31:64])``` ?

Comment: When you drop rows this way first you drop rows `3:10` then in changed dataframe rows `24:29`. So in original dataframe you drop rows `3:10 and (24 + 7):(29 + 7)`. Is it intended behavior?

Comment: ```np.r_``` generates all the indices before the drop occurs. of course, OP has to tell he wants

Comment: @V.Ayrat's point can be tackled with `loc` instead of `iloc` however, `np.r_` is the correct and the most efficient way to go.

Comment: I would indeed want to drop the rows between the indices (3, 10), (24, 29), and (31, 64) from the original dataframe and not like [3:10], then [24:29] in the modified dataframe, and so on as @V.Ayrat mentioned. So in this case is ```np.r_``` the best way to go?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue as @shona for a similar case in a project and the solution provided by @sammywemmy `df.drop(np.r_[3:10,24:29,31:64])` worked perfectly well for me. I could drop the specified ranges of rows from the original DataFrame all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to making df's out of slices is to [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the pieces you want to keep. Basically the inverse of dropping them.

```
df = pd.concat([df.head(3), df.iloc[10:24], df.iloc[29:31], df.iloc[64:-1]])
```

Comment: Can you comment on what makes this "the general approach" in your view? Is this because you feel it is more common, or does it have some concrete advantages over using `df.drop()`?